# how to change specific node value in xml using Dom php

Tags: php, xml, dom

Hi i want to change the value of cost to $6.0 where the color of cupcake is Red. how can i achieve that..here is my two sample cupcake though i have many cupcake in my xml file..so i want to first find the cupcake whose color is red and then change the corresponding cupcake price to whatever i like..

```
<cupcake>
    <name> Cookies and Cream</name>
    <flavours>
        <ingredient>Chocolate Cake</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Salted Caramel Buttercream</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Buttercream</ingredient>
    </flavours>
    <colors>
        <color>Red</color>
    </colors>
    <energy>1900.6Cal</energy>
    <cost>$22.50</cost>
</cupcake>

<cupcake>
    <name> Killer Carrot</name>
    <flavours>
        <ingredient>Carrot Spice cake</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Cream Cheese Frosting</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Candied Carrots</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Chocolate</ingredient>
    </flavours>
    <colors>
        <color>Aqua</color>
    </colors>
    <energy>1500.0KJ</energy>
    <cost>$15.80</cost>
</cupcake>
```

and my php file is

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();  
$xml->load('cupcakes.xml');  
if ($xml->schemaValidate('cupcakes.xsd')==FALSE)     
die ('<div class="error">Validation failed</div>'); 
$xsl = new DOMDocument(); 
$xsl->load('cupcakes.xsl'); 
$proc = new XSLTProcessor(); 
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules  
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
echo "<hr/>";

echo "<h2> the first cupcake having color red has changed the cost value to $6.0"; 

$a = $xml->getElementsByTagName('color');
foreach ($a->nodeValue as $A){
if ($A = "Red")
$a->getElementsByTagName('cost')->nodeValue="$6.00";
}

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml); 
?>
```

Comment: Use xpath `//cupcake[.//color[text() = "Red"]]/cost` to find needed element and change value. Maybe you should to wrap your xml with `'<root>'.$xml.'</root>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You XML is missing a document element. It is not a valid XML file.

`DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list, not a single node. `$nodeValue` is a property of `DOMNode`, not `DOMNodeList`. Just checking the color value, will not do it. A cupcake can have several colors. If you use XPath you can have conditions like that:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cupcake[colors/color = "Red"]/cost') as $cost) {
  $cost->nodeValue = '';
  $cost->appendChild($document->createTextNode('$6.00'));
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cupcakes>
<cupcake>
    <name> Cookies and Cream</name>
    <flavours>
        <ingredient>Chocolate Cake</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Salted Caramel Buttercream</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Buttercream</ingredient>
    </flavours>
    <colors>
        <color>Red</color>
    </colors>
    <energy>1900.6Cal</energy>
    <cost>$6.00</cost>
</cupcake>

<cupcake>
    <name> Killer Carrot</name>
    <flavours>
        <ingredient>Carrot Spice cake</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Cream Cheese Frosting</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Candied Carrots</ingredient>
        <ingredient>Chocolate</ingredient>
    </flavours>
    <colors>
        <color>Aqua</color>
    </colors>
    <energy>1500.0KJ</energy>
    <cost>$15.80</cost>
</cupcake>
</cupcakes>
```

XPath allows you to fetch nodes and scalar values. It this case:

Fetch all cupcake nodes... 
`//cupcake`

... with a color node that equals "Red"...
`//cupcake[colors/color = "Red"]`

...and get its cost child node:
`//cupcake[colors/color = "Red"]/cost`

Comment: Thank yoy so so so much..I am new in xml so i didnt realize that..thank you again..and my parent node is cupcakes which i didnt paste in my above file sry for that

Answer (score -1):

Tell us, what is wrong with your code, what is the error message if any...

and I suggest you try better the simpleXML usage since the syntax of it is way easier (to me). Here is a link you might check http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

The syntax you use in your example resembles the js one. but you can you use a more easy one in php

Comment: i did not get it and keep in mind that i have to use DOM..so can you please write a piece of code so that i can understand..

Comment: it doesnot change the value at all and says that  Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue in C:\wamp\www\Assignment\ChangeNodeValue.php on line 16